# I can't use all Arduino's analog pins

Tags: input, arduino, pins

I'm just an amateur and this might be a stupid question that requires a simple fix, but I can't find a solution online.
I'm working on a project in which I need to use a servo driver and a LCD screen.
The problem is that, according to the libraries' docs, both devices need to be plugged into the A4 and A5 analog pins.
Also, I can't find where the used pins are declared in the libraries' files (for what I know there may not be the need to do so, I've never modified a library).
Could you help me?

For context, I'm using the HCPCA9685.zip library for the driver and the LiquidCrystal_I2C.zip one for the LCD display.
The code I'm working on is:

```
//VERSION WITH BUTTONS AND DISPLAY, NO STEPPER

//Libraries
  #include <HCPCA9685.h> //for the driver
  #include <Wire.h>  //For the display
  #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // for the display
  #include <Keypad.h> //for the keypad

//Mantainance
  #define  I2CAdd 0x40
  const byte ROWS = 4; //defines rows and columns of the keypad
  const byte COLS = 4;
  HCPCA9685 HCPCA9685(I2CAdd); //Activates the driver
  char keys[ROWS][COLS] = { //Array to represent the buttons on the keypad
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
  };
  byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //pins the keypad is connected to
  byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 4, 3, 2};
  Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); // creates the keypad object
  LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); //creates the LCD object


//Costants
  int servo1_min = 0; //Servos' min and mac positions
  int servo1_max = 450;
  
  int servo2_min = 450;
  int servo2_max = 0;  //SERVO2 POS = 450 - SERVO1 POS

  int servo3_min = 400;
  int servo3_max = 0;

  int servo4_min = 0;
  int servo4_max = 370;

  int servo5_min = 0;
  int servo5_max = 400;
  
  int servo6_min = 0;
  int servo6_max = 300;

void setup() 
  {
  HCPCA9685.Init(SERVO_MODE); //Wakes up the driver
  HCPCA9685.Sleep(false);
  Serial.begin(9600); //Serial monitor adress
  lcd.backlight(); // Setup LCD with backlight and initialize
  lcd.init(); 

  Serial.print("1: Wake up\n2:...");

  lcd.clear();      
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
  lcd.print("LCD start");
  }
void loop() 
  {
  char key = keypad.getKey(); // Read the key from the keypad
  if (key == '1') {
  lcd.clear();      
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
  lcd.print("Wake up");
  delay(3000);
  wakeup();
  }
  }
//User defined functions
  void wakeup()
  {
  lcd.clear();      
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
  lcd.print("Wakeup strarting");
  delay(3000);
  HCPCA9685.Servo(0, servo1_min);
  HCPCA9685.Servo(2, servo2_min);
  delay(2000);
  HCPCA9685.Servo(4, servo3_min);
  delay(2000);
  HCPCA9685.Servo(6, servo4_min);
  delay(2000);
  HCPCA9685.Servo(8, servo5_min);
  delay(2000);
  HCPCA9685.Servo(10, servo6_min);
  }
```

I've tried expiciting the input with analogRead(), bit it really didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

In this case A4 and A5 are serving their alternate functions as SDA and SCL pins for the I2C bus.  I would suggest you read up on I2C and how it works.  Many things can share those pins for communication as long as they have different I2C addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned which Arduino board you are using, but assuming it is an Arduino Uno. `A4` and `A5` in Arduino Uno are just a label specifying that those pin are analog-capable and they are assigned to ADC channel 4 and channel 5 when using as analog pin. `A4` and `A5` are also defined as [SDA and SCL](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h#L48-L61) for I2C communication, they can also be used as digital pin `18` and `19` as well. They are not used as analog pins in this case and therefore no analogRead() to be called.

I2C is a bus, meaning that many devices can be connected to the same bus as long as they have different I2C addresses, HCPCA9685 is on address `0x40` and LCD is on `0x27` in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now I understand. I'm sorry I forgot to specify the board, it was actually an Arduino UNO. Thank you so much again, your answer was really usefoul